# How to add page with restriction notice?

Tags: copyright

How can I add on my thesis a page that has a restriction notice just after the cover page?

There is a similar question but for adding copyrighting stuff on the footnote. I don't want to have a footnote in every page.

I just want only the second page of the pdf document to be dedicated to that, which will say: "This thesis includes confidential material and should not be copied bla bla bla…"

Thank you.

Comment: Whats the problem with simply typing the desired text on the page?! Please be more concrete what your problem is an add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)!

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually thought that I had to use a command like \chapter \section etc.

I just wrote before the first chapter just by adding a new page (\newpage) and it worked well.

Comment: If my answer provides a solution to your problem, it would be nice if you accept it (by clicking the check mark below the voting arrows) :-) …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add text right after the title page, there's no need for special commands …

```
\documentclass{book}

% just to have smaller pages:
\usepackage[papersize={10cm,14cm}]{geometry}

\begin{document}
% Titlepage
\title{My Book}
\author{I}
\maketitle

% copyright note
Don't steel my thoughts!

% First chapter (or TOC ...)
\chapter*{Preface}
This book is about how to wirte copyright notes
right after a title page \dots

% etc.  ...
\end{document}
```

which will give a copyright page like this:

[image: first attempt of a copyright page]

Note that theres no need for manual page breaking since `\maketitle` starts a new page after setting up the title page and `\chapter` start a new page by itself, too.

Now it’s time for some improvements:

- add some more information, like `\copyright\,2013, by me`
- remove the page number with `\thispagestyle{empty}`
- the effects of the following commands should be restricted to the copyright
  page by adding a group, i.e. a pair of curly braces `{ ... }`
- shift the information a bit lower with `\vspace*{4cm}` or to the bottom of
  the page with `\vspace*{\fill}` (the asterisk `*` in the command name is
  necessary, because without it the space will be ignored at the beginning of
  a page)
- set the indent to zero with `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`
- set some space between paragraphs with `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselinskip}`
  (with that setting there will be an empty line between the paragraphs)
- make the font smaller with `\footnotesize` and maybe italic with `\itshape`

Then we have the improved code

```
\documentclass{book}

% just to have smaller pages:
\usepackage[papersize={10cm,14cm}]{geometry}

\begin{document}
% Titlepage
\title{My Book}
\author{I}
\maketitle

% copyright note
{% begin group
   \vspace*{65mm}
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \footnotesize\itshape
   \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
   \copyright\,2013, by me

   Don't steel my thoughts!
}% end group

% First chapter (or TOC ...)
\chapter*{Preface}
This book is about how to wirte copyright notes
right after a title page \dots

% etc.  ...
\end{document}
```

resulting in a page like this:

[image: improved copyright page]

Comment: You mean _steal_ instead of _steel_.

Comment: @Aditya: No ;-) O:-) – I keep “steel” ’cause I’m too lazy to change the screenshot :-P